# Where can I find items with +INT in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

I'm looking for the lab coat with +2 INT, and glasses with +2 INT / -1 CHA.
Where can I find those?

Comment: Random drops are random

Comment: VTLO: "They drop randomly" is a perfectly valid answer.

Comment: I'm about 25 hours in and haven't found any of those yet. My best bet would looking for legendary drops with the desired stats. I've seen a few armor pieces with +1 INT & CHA. You can also upgrade power armor pieces to provide bonuses to these attributes.

Comment: FWIW, I found the Vault-tec Lab Coat (+2 int) on the East aside of downtown Boston, somewhere within a couple of blocks of Boston Commons. I didn't notice when it appeared in my inventory, so it could have been a random drop.

Comment: Also pipers hat adds 1 int and can be worn with glasses(yes I stole her hat)

Comment: Well, I do know that you can get a +INT headgear (only +1 though) from a named bandit in the Thicket Excavation a while after you helped the guy there to remove the water from the pond.

Comment: Why is this too broad? It's a rather specific question.

Comment: A) Closing this as too broad is completely absurd. B) Random drops may be random, but there are plenty of predetermined items laying around. A good answer would focus on those, not random drops.

Answer (score 4):

The regular [Lab Coat](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Lab_coat_(Fallout_4)) (*+2 INT*) can be found in the following locations:

> - Anne Hargraves sells one if she is assigned to a clothing store.
> - A lab coat can be obtained if one is given the lab assistant job during the Cambridge Polymer Labs quest.
> - Patricia Montgomery at Covenant wears one.
> - Tinker Tom sells an armored lab coat.
> - Doc Crocker's lab coat can be looted from his body after the quest *The Disappearing Act*.
> - Worn by Doc Carrington and T.S. Wallace.
> - Doctor Sun and Doc Weathers wear one.
> - Worn by Doctor Amari in Memory Den.
> - Worn by Miranda Song at Vault 81.
> - (Far Harbor DLC) Teddy Wright wears a lab coat.
>     The [Institute lab coat variants](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Institute_lab_coat), the [Vault-Tec lab coat](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Vault-Tec_lab_coat_(Fallout_4)), [Father's lab coat](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Father%27s_lab_coat), and [Cabot's lab coat](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Cabot%27s_lab_coat) also give a +2 INT bonus.

The glasses you are referring to are [**Liam's glasses**](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Liam%27s_glasses) (*+2 INT, -1 CHA*), and can be found during:

> the quest [*Plugging a Leak*](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Plugging_a_Leak), given by Justin Ayo at the Institute, available after *Mankind - Redefined*. You must side with Liam in framing Justin, and pass the speech check for additional rewards to obtain the glasses.
>   Be aware that this quest will be unavailable if you have completed *Tradecraft*, which is an early quest, making these easily missed.

---

Other items that give an Intelligence bonus:

- Permanent effect:

  - Bobblehead: [Intelligence](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Intelligence_bobblehead), INT +1 (*"In the northwest room of the [Boston Public Library](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Boston_Public_Library) sitting on a control*").
  - Perk: [Night Person](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Night_Person_(perk)), +2 / +3 INT (between 6 PM and 6 AM).
  - Construction: [Overseer's Desk](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Overseer%27s_desk), +1 INT (Vault-Tec Workshop DLC, limited)
  - Level: [S.P.E.C.I.A.L. ability](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Fallout_4_primary_statistics), +1 INT / level (up to 10, opting for a S.P.E.C.I.A.L. bonus instead of a perk)
- Semi-permanent effect:

  - Outfit: [Destroyer's Helmet](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Destroyer%27s_helmet), +1 INT ("*sold by Penny Fitzgerald in Covenant*").
  - Outfit: [Institute Division Head coat variants](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Institute_division_head_coat), +1 INT.
  - Outfit: [Mechanic jumpsuit variants](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Mechanic_jumpsuit_(Fallout_4)), +1 INT.
  - Outfit: [Fancy suit & tie](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Fancy_suit_%26_tie), +1 INT (Nuka World DLC).
  - Outfit: [Acadia's Shield](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Acadia%27s_Shield), +1 INT (Far Harbor DLC: "*Given by DiMA if* The Way Life Should Be *quest is completed in his favor*").
  - Headwear: [The Captain's Hat](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/The_Captain%27s_Hat), +2 INT (Far Harbor DLC).
  - Headwear: [Inquisitor's Cowl](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Inquisitor%27s_cowl), +1 INT (Far Harbor DLC).
  - Headwear: [Mechanist's Helmet](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Mechanist%27s_armor), +1 INT (Automatron DLC).
  - Headwear: [Press cap](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Press_cap), +1 INT.
  - Headwear: [Tinker headgear](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Tinker_headgear), +1 INT.
  - Headgear: [Ushanka hat](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Ushanka_hat_(Fallout_4)), +1 INT.
  - Glasses: [Road goggles](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Road_goggles_(Fallout_4)), +1 INT.
  - Weapon: [Legendary 'Sharp' effect](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Legendary_armor_effects#Legendary_armor_prefixes), +1 INT.
- Temporary effect:

  - Consumable: [Berry Mentats](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Berry_Mentats_(Fallout_4)), +5 INT.
  - Consumable: [Daddy-O](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Daddy-O_(Fallout_4)), +3 INT.
  - Consumable: [Mentats](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Mentats_(Fallout_4)), +2 INT.
  - Consumable: [X-Cell](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/X-cell_(Fallout_4)), +2 INT.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that you can get a +2 int lab coat from the quest "The Dissappearing Act". It's on the body of one of the doctor at the end. You get the quest by picking up the case file in Nick Valentine's office.

As mentioned by  [z '](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/3917/z) you get get +1 int from pipers cap. You can take it from her inventory without stealing if she is your companion.

**I don't yet know if there is any specific place you can get glasses with +int.**

Apart from that there seems to be lots of +int gear on random drops as mentioned by several users ([Ben](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/125500/ben) [Schism](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/31508/schism) [kalina](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/52800/kalina)).

Comment: If you have the Automatron DLC, then you can get Road Goggles (+1 to INT) on one of the bodies where you find Ada.

Answer (score 0):

I picked up a lab coat and glasses from the Becky Fallon, the clothing trader  in Diamond City.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the Vault-Tec lab coat in Vault 111 from one of the dressers in the sleeping quarters behind the overseer's desk.