# Where can I find the Vault-Tec lab coat?

Tags: fallout-4

The Fallout wiki lists this apparel item as being in the dockhouse south of the Harbormaster hotel. I think I found the place (with a dead brahmin outside) but its suitcase contains a Postman Uniform. Where can I find this +2 INT coat?

Edit: I also checked Vault 111 again and you cannot loot the skeletons or overseer—they just have an "Activate" function and your character says that everyone is dead. I didn't see the lab coat anywhere else there.

Comment: Pretty sure I had one before I even left Vault 111.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I thought I did too, but I loaded my save and I don't see it.

Comment: This might actually be a duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/243203/108003

Comment: @ヴァイシャリ I don't yet have the quests in the later two answers but I'll check whether they're correct

Comment: @ヴァイシャリ This question could be made more objective by asking about the one easiest to get to at the start of the game.

Comment: I spent some time last night trying to figure out where my characters got their coats. I keep a lot of saves, so I was able to narrow it down and determine the first save where each character had the coat. From there, I compared the world map with the one on the previous save with the same character to determine which locations had been discovered in the interim. I then loaded the earlier save and checked these locations, but was unable to find it. This leads me to believe they were both random drops. Notably, both characters visited Abernathy Farms and Bedford station in that interval.

Comment: I noticed Dr. Amari is wearing one of these, if you can figure out a way to get it off of her. Maybe start with flowers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Cambridge polymer labs and vault 81 contains guaranteed lab coats.

Just be aware there are quests in both locations that you must start before you are able to access the area with the lab coats.

Comment: @Sean you start the quests in the same areas they are located

Answer (score 2):

You can come to the settlement called "Covenant".

After your investigation there, you come to the "Covenant Compound". While clearing it you will find a lot of Vault-tec lab coats.

It is part of the mission "The Human Error".

Comment: I dunno about "a lot". I know I found one. I think all the rest were just normal Lab Coats.

Comment: I only found one, on Blythe (the scientist you meet behind the door)

Answer (score 0):

It's located in a locked suitcase at a boat shack just south of Harbormaster hotel. I found the clothing that you found in another shack, so keep looking around

Comment: It's somewhere else as well, as both my characters have it and I don't believe I've ever been to that shack. I'll look for it again at some point.

Comment: Yes, its seems that it would likely be in a few vaults as well, it makes sense

Comment: I said in my original post that I looked there and found something else

Comment: @Sean Baibro is contending that you looked in the wrong building, and citing experience that corroborates that.

Comment: SPOILERS: I've found some Vault Tec lab coats during the molerat extermination quest in vault 81.

Answer (score 0):

This might have been added later.. but you can get the Vault tec lab coat in Vault 111 in one of the dressers in the sleeping quarters behind the overseers desk.